# Calling myModel.save() Returning Outdated Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am attempting to save an Ember Data `DS.Model` after it's been updated, but when I call `myModel.save()`, I'm finding that Ember Data is sending the **original, non-updated** model instead of the updated one.  I'm trying to understand why this is happening and what I need to do differently.

Here are some details.  First, I have two models:

**/models/OrgUser.js:**

```
DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    orgPerson: DS.belongsTo('org-person', { inverse: 'org-user', async: true, embedded: 'always' }),
});
```

Note that I am using a customized `RESTSerializer` (see below), so the only use of `embedded: 'always'` is how my custom `RESTSerializer` handles it.

**/models/OrgPerson.js:**

```
DS.Model.extend({
   ...
   orgUser: DS.belongsTo('org-user'),
})
```

To persist these models, I'm using the `RESTAdapter`. In an attempt to generate a single JSON request to my API that contains both models above, I've made a single customization to the adapter.  I don't think this is affecting anything, but just in case I'm missing something, here it is:

**/serializers/application.js:**

```
DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key;
        key = this.keyForRelationship ? this.keyForRelationship(key, 'belongsTo') : key;

        var data = record.get('data');

        if (relationship.options.embedded && relationship.options.embedded === 'always') {
            json[key] = data[relationship.key] ? data[relationship.key].get('data') : null;
        }
        else {
            json[key] = data[relationship.key] ? data[relationship.key].get('id') : null;
        }

        if (relationship.options.polymorphic) {
          this.serializePolymorphicType(record, json, relationship);
        }
    }
})
```

With that setup, I have a template where I update the orgPerson properties.  I can confirm these are bound properties because updating their input updates their display on another part of the template in real-time.  I then call an `action` on my controller, and within that action do the following:

**/controllers/my-page.js:**

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend( FormMixin, {
   actions: {
        submitForm: function() {
            ...
            this.get('model') // Chrome console shows that _data.orgPerson._data.firstName has the (incorrect) old property
            this.get('model').serialize() // returns (incorrect) old firstName
            this.get('orgPerson.firstName') // returns (correct) updated firstName
            this.get('orgPerson').get('firstName') // returns (correct) updated firstName
         ...
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea why I am getting two different versions of the same model?  How can I serialize the correctly updated model?  Thanks for any input!

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks (again!) to @kingpin2k, I have resolved this issue.  Here are the steps I took:

- My serializer was in fact the problem, and using Ember's old preserved data.  I replaced the line `data[relationship.key].get('data')` with the line `data[relationship.key].serialize()` and this was fixed.
- I then ran into another issue, which was that if I edited my record, did NOT save it, and then went back to my list of records, the list still showed the edit.  My first thought was that I needed to update my list page's array `model` to show only the latest content, but there didn't appear to be any Ember facilities for this.
- So I ultimately solved this by using the following code in my route. Note that because `orgPerson` is `async: true` I had to wrap my model in a promise.  Note also that I had to directly call `model.orgPerson` versus just `model`.

**Updated route:**

```
actions: {
    willTransition: function( transition ) {
        this.controller.get('model.orgPerson').then( function( value ) {
            if ( value.get('isDirty') ) {
                value.rollback(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- Going forward, I just want to call `this.controller.get('model').rollback()`, so I'm going to write  a util function that traverses `eachRelationship` and then individually calls `rollback()` on any of the objects.  Whew, a lot of subtlety to get this working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data stores the original values in the `data` obj.  It stores modified values in `_attributes` obj.  During a save it moves `_attributes` obj to `inFlightAttributes` obj, then after the save is complete it merges them from `inFlightAttributes` to `data`.  All of this is so you can rollback your record.

When you define a property as `attr` it hooks up the magical get where it first checks `_attributes`, then `inFlightAttributes`, then `data` and returns that property's result.

```
function getValue(record, key) {
  if (record._attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return record._attributes[key];
  } else if (record._inFlightAttributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return record._inFlightAttributes[key];
  } else {
    return record._data[key];
  }
}
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L267

In your case, Ember Data doesn't know you are saving that record, and you are manually grabbing the old properties from the `data` obj.  You'd either need to manually merge `_attributes` to `data` or trick Ember Data into thinking you'd saved it.

Comment: ah, that explains it! So my serializer is in fact the culprit. I was able to update my serializer to use `data[relationship.key].serialize()` instead of `data[relationship.key].get('data')`.  Would that be the recommended way of handling this situation?

Comment: I'm also running into an issue where changes on my Edit page (the subject of my original question) are immediately reflected in my `ArrayController`'s backing array, whereas I'd like to only show `_data` properties (i.e. confirmed saved properties).  Within the `arrayController`, I'm using `this.get('arrangedContent')`. Is there an alternate way to get only "saved" data that is also filtered? Thx for your help; this really clarifies things for me!

Comment: That's a common problem people have been facing, essentially you'd need to copy the properties to an alternate object on the edit page, then copy it back to the real ember data record.  There is no other way to say get committed versus get not committed data.  Ember Data will always return the latest change, committed or not.

Comment: ok, I solved my second problem.  I'll put the details in my original question, but basically I wound up (1) using the `willTransition` event on my route so that whenever the route exits, I can (2) `rollback()` the `DS.Model`.  Of course, I then discovered that `rollback()` is not recursive, so calling it on `orgUser` did NOT affect `orgPerson`.  For that, I'm going to wind up writing a custom function to load `eachRelationship` of `orgUser`, check if `isDirty`, and if so, `rollback()`.  Wow, did not expect this to be so nuanced.  Thanks again for your help. I'll accept your answer now.