# Editing a record in Ember without updating the UI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember and Ember-Data and I'm trying to edit a record. The problem is that since inputs are two-way-bound to the model, modifying something in the form immediately changes the model throughout the application (even though I don't commit the changes). Hence, the changes reflect everywhere in the site even though they aren't stored.

What is the Ember way of editing records without modifying them until the user actually confirms the changes? Is there a way to clone models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's really funny, I just myself ran into this, came up with a solution, and documented it in my own Stack Overflow question at [Calling myModel.save() Returning Outdated Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25348818/2308858).  Scroll down to the SOLUTION part, second bullet.

My perception is that this pattern, while very common, is still not well-documented in the Ember community. For example, see these recent discussions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25350828/2308858 (See comments)
- http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/before-leaving-route/2328

I solved this by doing the following:

- Hook into the `willTransition` event in your route so that, whenever your page that is doing the editing is transitioned out of, you can execute code right before that happens.  Note that this covers both *clicking* your way out, or *back-button'ing* out. If the user closes their browser, these changes are lost anyway, so nothing extra needed to handle that situation.
- Now in that hook, get your model with `this.controller.get('model')` and look at the value of `isDirty` with `this.controller.get('model').get('isDirty')`.  See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/working-with-records/ for discussion on how to understand `isDirty`.
- If `isDirty` is true, then call `rollback()` on your model as documented at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback.
- This will revert any unsaved changes so that the rest of your app looks consistent.

I have a model `orgUser` which has a `belongsTo` relationship to a model `orgPerson`.  This relationship is set to `{ async: true }`.  Rolling back the `orgPerson` relationship worked like this for me:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        willTransition: function( transition ) {
        this.controller.get('model.orgPerson').then( function( value ) {
            if ( value.get('isDirty') ) {
                value.rollback();
                }
            });
        },
    }
}
```

Note that you (a) may not need to wrap your `isDirty` call in a promise like I did (e.g. if you don't declare `{ async: true }`, and (b) you may just access `value.get('model')` if you don't have a relationship to deal with.

Note also that, in my experience, `myModel.rollback()` does not rollback any of the relationships!  That may only be because I'm using `{ async: true }` for every relationship, but this is definitely something to watch out for.

Special thanks to @kingpin2k for pointing me in the right direction on my original SO post.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was kind of hoping to avoid doing the rollback thing because my edit form actually displays the records title, so while editing the form you actually see the title change, which looks odd, but apparently this is the best solution out there.

Comment: Are you saying you'd prefer that your title on the edit form NOT update its title in real time?  If so, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/25350828/2308858.  You may be able to get the unsaved data with `myModel._data[ propertyName ]`.  Though, to be clear, this is probably meant as a private method, not part of the public API.